# Convert 32 bit ASM to 64 bit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, inline-assembly, masm, intrinsics

I know that inline assembly is not supported in x64. I'm not so familiar with assembly so I would like to ask anyone well versed in it to help me. Can anyone convert this code from 32 bit to 64 bit? I've read you can use MASM or compiler intrinsics but a bit confused how to convert this code.

```
#define get_member_function_address_vc8(member_function_address, member_function_type)\
void* member_function_address;          \
{                                       \
    __asm                               \
{                                       \
    mov eax,offset member_function_type \
};                                      \
__asm                                   \
{                                       \
    mov member_function_address, eax    \
};                                      \
}
```

Regards, Mark

Comment: the 64 bit register analog to eax is called rax

Comment: What are you trying to do? This macro declares (not calls) a function that moves the contents of its second argument into first argument, that's it. Also, it's very old-fashioned C that modern compilers might not like (K&R argument type declaration, implicit int).

Comment: What is `member_function_type`?

Comment: Also be aware that if you are using Visual Studio, it doesn't support inline asm for 64bit code.  So whatever you are trying to do, you'll need to do it very differently.

Comment: member_function_type is a class. This is part of a legacy code that we are trying to migrate from 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ugg... that's some ugly, ugly code. As David Wohlferd said in his comment Visual C++ doesn't support inline assembly when targeting 64-bit processors so you need to do something different.

First I'll try to explain what this macro is trying to accomplish. All the assembly instructions are doing is assigning a 32-bit value taken from the second macro argument to a variable declared with the name passed in as the first argument. What's it doing seems to be the equivalent of this macro:

```
#define get_member_function_address(varname, member_function) \
     void *varname = (void *)&(member_function);
```

The fact the that macro is called `get_member_function_address` gives us a clue why the author of the macro felt it necessary to go to the extreme length of using inline assembly just to get the address of an object. It's trying to get the address of a member function,  but this isn't easy. Using the unary `&` operator on a member function does give you a pointer to the member function like you expect, but pointers to member functions are special in C++. They represent more than just the address of the member function, so you can't cast them to `void *`.

Unfortunately, there's no portable way to find the address of a member function in C++. The macro assumes that a pointer to member function object has the address of the function located at the start of the object. However a compiler can put it anywhere it wants. Apparently this assumption is correct for the 32-bit version of Visual Studio 2005 (VS8), but I don't know if it's also true for any other version.

Assuming that it hasn't changed than the following code should be a drop in replacement for the macro. It should work when targeting both 32-bit and 64-bit environments.  That is, assuming that pointers to member functions have the address of the member function at the start.

```
template <class T>
static inline void *
_get_member_function_address(T member_function_ptr) {
    union {
        T mf;
        void *p;
    } u;
    u.mf = member_function_ptr;
    return u.p;
}

#define get_member_function_address_vs8(varname, member_function)   \
    void *varname = _get_member_function_address(&member_function);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is part of a legacy code that we are trying to migrate from 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS. Will try to check out this code as soon I can.